# Оптимизация кода Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Программа тянет за курсором rigidbody, курсор стреляет рейкастом. 
Почему то во время движения дико начинает притормаживать всё. Без движения 72 fps, с ним 6 fps. 
Что это и как с этим бороться. GetComponent в Update вроде нет.

Содержимое скрипта, который тормозит. Отключил остальные - всё равно, максимум 15 fps в движении.

```
public class RayCaster : MonoBehaviour {
    private Ray ray;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    public float speedphys;
    public GameObject player;
    Rigidbody rb;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    void FixedUpdate() // так как мы работаем с физикой в Unity, FixedUpdate предпочтительнее обычного Update
    {
        //Под разные платформы нам требуется разный код.
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        ForUnityEditorAndPC();

    #endif
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        ForAndro();
    #endif
    #if UNITY_STANDALONE
        ForUnityEditorAndPC();
    #endif

    }

    void ForUnityEditorAndPC()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); // Если дело имеем с компьютеров - из мышки луч пускаем
            raycast();
        }
    }
    void ForAndro()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position); //     Если андроид - то из тача, когда он движется.
            raycast();

        }
    }
    void raycast()//Этот код для обоих устройств общий, нет смысла его дублировать. Тут мы смотрим, куда упал луч
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && !hit.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
        {


            var dir = (hit.point - player.transform.position);

            player.transform.DOLookAt(hit.point, 0.1f);
            Debug.Log(hit.point);
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(dir.x, 0, dir.z) * speedphys;
            //Двигаем коллайдер к месту куда луч упал. Rigidbody используем, так как физика, да и силы слишком много быть
            //не должно - а то раскидает фишки остальные. С параметром speedphys легко регулировать скорость коллайдера прямо
            //из редактора, не заглядывая лишний раз в код.
            Debug.Log(hit.point + " hitpoint");
            //Debug.Log(transform.position + " transform.position");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перенес код из Update в корутину. 
При 20 обновлениях в секунду(0.05 секунд ожидание в корутине) устойчивый fps 70-80. Проблема не проявляется.

```
void Start () {
    rb = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    StartCoroutine(cur());

}

// Update is called once per frame
IEnumerator cur() // так как мы работаем с физикой в Unity, FixedUpdate предпочтительнее обычного Update
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        //Под разные платформы нам требуется разный код.
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        ForUnityEditorAndPC();

#endif
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        ForAndro();
#endif
#if UNITY_STANDALONE
    ForUnityEditorAndPC();
#endif

    }
}
```